# Ksoap2 complicated reaquest for beginners

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

How can i create ksoap2 request for this xml.

```html
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:tem="http://temp.net/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetForexStock>
         <tem:request>
            <tem:IsIPAD>true</tem:IsIPAD>
            <tem:DeviceID>test</tem:DeviceID>
            <tem:DeviceType>ipad</tem:DeviceType>
            <tem:RequestKey>myKey</tem:RequestKey>
            <tem:RequestedSymbol>?</tem:RequestedSymbol>
            <tem:Period>Day</tem:Period>
         </tem:request>
      </tem:GetForexStock>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried requesting with soap object, but it does not work, i dont know what to do, little help will be appreciated

Comment: I need the answer for this web service. Do you add properties as you add for simple request with soapObject.addProperty("IsIPAD", "true");
What about <tem:request> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to create a `SoapObject` and pass it to `bodyOut` property of envelope.

```
SoapObject sub = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);
  sub.addProperty("strCode", value);
  envelope.bodyOut = sub;
```

Comment: What is strCode and value for this example? Do you use request tag for adding properties?